# How to select cumulative counts by group over time across in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

I have cumulative counts for two groups over time in this format:

| Date | Group | Cumulative Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | A | 1 |
| 1/2/2020 | A | 3 |
| 1/2/2020 | B | 1 |
| 1/3/2020 | B | 2 |

And I'd like to reshape this data into this format:

| Date | Group | Cumulative Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | A | 1 |
| 1/1/2020 | B | 0 |
| 1/2/2020 | A | 3 |
| 1/2/2020 | B | 1 |
| 1/3/2020 | A | 3 |
| 1/3/2020 | B | 2 |

So that I can get it to display accurately in a stacked area chart in metabase - any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may generate all possible pairs of dates and groups with a cross join before using a left join to get the combined dataset eg

Since your dataset already has the cumulative counts, the missing values identified by null have been replaced using  the most recent cumulative count with `MAX` and `COALESCE`.

```sql
SELECT
    d."Date"::text,
    d."Group",
    COALESCE(m."CumulativeCount",COALESCE(MAX(m."CumulativeCount") OVER (
        PARTITION BY d."Group"
        ORDER BY d."Date"
    ),0)) as CumulativeCount
FROM (
    SELECT "Date", "Group" FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            "Date"
        FROM
            my_data
    ) t1
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            "Group"
        FROM
            my_data
    ) t2
) d 
LEFT JOIN my_data m ON m."Date"=d."Date" AND
                       m."Group" = d."Group"
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

| Date | Group | cumulativecount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | B | 0 |
| 2020-01-02 | A | 3 |
| 2020-01-02 | B | 1 |
| 2020-01-03 | A | 3 |
| 2020-01-03 | B | 2 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t4SABAXtA23XhqEn58Ctqn/0)

#### Update 1

If it is that you would like to generate values for dates between missing dates eg you had the next date to be `1/7/2020` and you wanted to fill the gaps for `1/3/2020` you could use `generate_series` to generate the possible dates and `MAX` to get the most recent value. I have included a fiddle below with additional sample data eg

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (
  "Date" DATE,
  "Group" VARCHAR(1),
  "CumulativeCount" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_data
  ("Date", "Group", "CumulativeCount")
VALUES
  ('1/1/2020', 'A', '1'),
  ('1/2/2020', 'A', '3'),
  ('1/2/2020', 'B', '1'),
  ('1/3/2020', 'B', '2'),
  ('1/1/2020', 'C', '2'),
  ('1/7/2020', 'C', '3');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    d."Date"::text,
    d."Group",
    COALESCE(
        m."CumulativeCount",
        COALESCE(MAX(m."CumulativeCount") OVER (
            PARTITION BY d."Group"
            ORDER BY d."Date"
        ),0)
    ) as CumulativeCount
FROM (
    SELECT "Date", "Group" FROM (
        SELECT
            GENERATE_SERIES(
                MIN("Date"),
                MAX("Date"),
                INTERVAL '1' DAY
            ) as "Date"
        FROM
            my_data
    ) t1
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            "Group"
        FROM
            my_data
    ) t2
) d 
LEFT JOIN my_data m ON m."Date"=d."Date" AND
                       m."Group" = d."Group"
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

| Date | Group | cumulativecount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00 | A | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00 | B | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00 | C | 2 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | A | 3 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | B | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | C | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00+00 | A | 3 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00+00 | B | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00+00 | C | 2 |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00+00 | A | 3 |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00+00 | B | 2 |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00+00 | C | 2 |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00+00 | A | 3 |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00+00 | B | 2 |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00+00 | C | 2 |
| 2020-01-06 00:00:00+00 | A | 3 |
| 2020-01-06 00:00:00+00 | B | 2 |
| 2020-01-06 00:00:00+00 | C | 2 |
| 2020-01-07 00:00:00+00 | A | 3 |
| 2020-01-07 00:00:00+00 | B | 2 |
| 2020-01-07 00:00:00+00 | C | 3 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2g4t81ehP945H6YgZwzXvY/3)

Comment: For date "2020-01-03" and group "A", the value must be 3 according to desired output

Comment: @Arun Thank you. I hadn't noticed this. I've updated the answer

Comment: @ggordon ah-hah, that makes sense - thanks, this works perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following steps:

**Note**: I have created few tables. Feel free to use sub-query or CTE depending on your preference.

Firstly, creating possible `date-group` pairs:

```
create table ads as 
SELECT
    sq."date",
    sq."group",
    COALESCE(m."cummulativecount",0) as CummulativeCount
FROM 
(
    SELECT "date", "group" 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT "date"
        FROM tbl
    ) dt
    
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT "group"
        FROM tbl
    ) grp
) sq 
LEFT JOIN tbl m 
   ON m."date"=sq."date" 
   AND
   m."group" = sq."group"
```

(The above step was referenced from @ggordon's answer). Now, Since we imputed all cummulativeCount as 0 for additional records, we have to get recent cummulativeCount for the actual table (i.e., for **A**, `3` will be taken from `"1/2/2020"`. If recent most value is unavailable, then it will not be taken.

```
create table prev_cnt as 
select t."group", t.cummulativecount 
from tbl as t
inner join 
(
   select tbl."group", max(tbl."date") m_date
   from ads 
   inner join tbl
      on ads."group"=tbl."group"
   where ads.cummulativecount =0 and
      tbl."date" < ads."date"
   group by tbl."group"
) as sq
   on t."group"=sq."group" 
   and t."date"=sq.m_date
```

Finally, joining the recent most values with derived ads table:

```
create table fin_ads as 
select 
   ads."date", 
   ads."group", 
   case 
     when ads.cummulativecount=0 and pc.cummulativecount IS NOT NULL then pc.cummulativecount 
     else ads.cummulativecount 
   end as cummulativecount
from ads
LEFT join prev_cnt as pc
   on ads."group"=pc."group"
```

The table `fin_ads` will be your desired output.

sample code and date here: [*DB<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=527153f537a02ceb6d4f2e0115133a22)

Comment: This approach works too, however can you suggest one with less joins for the Op?. More joins are usually more expensive, see query plan using ctes and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` comparison [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e6caebb1f79a3cb6204a1a4be7134652)

Comment: Thanks @ggordon! I realize using more JOINS would be more expensive than 1 function.